# I'm curious about the token issuance process through OAuth2.0 authentication in POSTMAN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman, cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bWbY.png)

I'm trying to get a token from POSTMAN through OAuth2.0 authentication, but if the grant type is Client Credentials, the error keeps popping up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRTry.png)

To link files using Cloud Storage on the Google Cloud Platform, POSTMAN is testing OAuth2 authentication to get tokens to access buckets
I want to set the grant type as Client Credentials in the settings, but I keep getting errors, so how can I get a token?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.